# "Back to the 1995." VS "Back to 1995."

Tags: articles

Which form is corect in English:

> Back to the 1995.

OR

> Back to 1995.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form without the article is correct. Year names don't take articles ever. In general dates don't take articles, but there are exceptions:

I'm going to Canada in 2015.
I'm going to Canada in May.
I'm going to Canada on May 5th.
I'm going to Canada on Thursday,

BUT

I'm going to Canada the Thursday after next.
I'm going to Canada on the 5th of May.

I don't see a pattern. I hope someone can help.

Comment: Derfder is probably thinking of "the '90s", which would be a correct way to refer to that decade.

Comment: What about "I got married back in **the year** 1995"? Or "We first met **back in** 1995." Or "Reminiscing, Jim went **back to** 1995, when he was just 18 years old."

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't see any articles there, though. Well, *the* in *the year*, but that's modifying *year*, not *1995*.